# How to align <div> elements?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center two  elements to make columns. I also want a footer. However, They are stacked next to each other and the footer element is inline with everything. How can I format the page correctly?

```css
h1 {
    color: #225522;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px 0px;
} 
img {
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-color: #484848;
    font: Trebuchet MS;
}

p.heading {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#rn_section1 {
    text-align: center;
    height: 495px;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#rn_section2 {
    text-align: center;
    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: inherit;
}
```

Comment: First of all, there is no JS, HTML nor PHP in your post, I'm removing the tags. Then, can you show the us your DOM?

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari, clearly nothing. Let's at least *attempt* to be nice to obvious first time posters.

Comment: @azium I think that was in response to Alan Machado's question

Comment: @azium Jeez. that was a question not a nuke attack.

Comment: I think @HawasKaPujaari was asking why we would need JS or PHP, directed towards Alan Machado.

Comment: OP tagged this with JS and PHP, along with HTML and CSS.  Those tags have been removed.

Comment: ^End of chit chat. Let's just wait for a constructive edit and not flood it with _who's got the game here_ x)

Comment: [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)...just sayin'! :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is vague. But trying to help the newbie. Okay, for those two `<div>`s, can you please give the following CSS:

1. Children:

   ```css
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   ```
2. Parent:

   ```css
   overflow: hidden;
   ```

The above CSS will make the children, take up a width of `50%` each and make them in the center. If you want both the parent and children to be fixed, in your case, you need to give the parent, the following CSS:

```css
width: 800px; /* As both the children are of 400px */
margin: auto;
```